# Dokku: Need some guidance in serving frontend (vue) and backend (django, drf)

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework, dokku

I recently moved over to using Dokku and am wondering if someone can help me out with this. I am trying to run Vue and Django on a Linode server. Currently I have Django serving at my IP. Looks like in nginx, that port 80 is being listened to and Django is being served at /. I'd like to move Django to either be served at ':8000' as it is on my local machine or to be served at '/backend'. Then I'd like to serve Vue the way Django is currently being served () and it can hit the api at either previously mentioned Django location.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just throwing Vue up on netlify and that worked great.